# Replacing characters in renaming

Tags: python, rename, maya

I am trying to do a simple Maya renaming UI but I am stuck at a part - replacing  he initial characters in the current naming with other characters

For example; 3 items in the Outliner(irregardless of what they are):- pCube1, - pSphere1, - nurbsSphere1

So far I am able to write up to the point where it can selects and rename 1 or more objects, see code below

```
objects = []
objects = cmds.ls(sl=True)
for obj in objects:
    test = []
    test = cmds.rename(obj, "pSphere" )
    print objects
    # Results: pSphere, pSphere2, pSphere3 #
```

However, suppose now I am selecting nurbsSphere1 and pSphere1, and I just wanted to  replace the word 'Sphere' in them with 'Circle', instead of getting the results as: `nurbsCircle1, pCircle1`, I got a error message `# TypeError: Too many objects or values. #`

```
charReplace = "test"
if charReplace in objects:
    newName = []
    newName = cmds.rename(objects, "Circle" )
```

Any advices on it?

Comment: shouldn't it be `newName = cmds.rename(charReplace, "Circle")`?

Comment: Hi, I tried it before, and it actually replace my whole string to `Circle` instead of the targeted character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As per the [documentation](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/index.html?url=files/Python_Using_Python.htm,topicNumber=d30e725553) rename command takes only strings as input parameters. You are providing a list named `objects` while trying to rename the filenames.
2. Moreover, you are searching for string `"test"` in `objects` list.
   Instead you should search for string `"test"` in each filename which is present in objects list.
3. `rename` command renames the old string with the newer one. It does not replace the substring within a string (e.g. "sphere" in "nurbsSphere"). In order to achieve this you should create the new filenames separately and then use them to rename the files.

You can try this:

```
charReplace = "test"
for filename in objects:
    if charReplace in filename:
        newFilename = filename.replace(charReplace, "Circle")
        cmds.rename(filename, newFilename)
```

I do not have Maya installed so code is not tested.

Comment: cool, it works... I persume that since I am able to get my first part running, the latter will works about the same. Guess I am very wrong and also, that my understanding of how python works is still not there yet

Comment: In the first part, you have also done the same thing. You took `obj` one by one from `objects` (using for loop) and then renamed them.
If you want to learn Python, I would suggest these 3 links:
1. [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/), 2.
[Interactive Python tutorial](http://www.learnpython.org/) and 3.
[Python for beginners](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/).

As you have mentioned that the given solution works. Please accept it as an answer.